# Configurable Contact Form with reCAPTCHA?

Tags: php, html, recaptcha, contact-form

I've been looking all over the web for the last hour (and several times before today), for a nice simple contact form that utilizes reCAPTCHA, and is easily configurable. I need to be able to easily create new fields and require fields without having to go in and write a ton of PHP (which I only have a basic understanding of).

List of Requirements:

- Easily create new fields, as simple as: `input type="text" name="example-name"`
- Easily specify which fields are required, something similar to: `input type="hidden" name="required" value="field-name,field-name"`
- Easily set the email address the form should send to, something similar to: `input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="email@example.com"`

All the code samples are just examples, obviously they can differ, I just need something similarly simple. I'll be using this script across many different websites, so simplicity is a necessity. I'd like to use reCAPTCHA, but it can be some other form of CAPTCHA if necessary.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way is to use [wufoo](http://wufoo.com), which support [recaptcha](http://wufoo.com/features/#feature13).

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using Wordpress? I have a great plugin for that.

Comment: Nope, it'll be used on many different sites, almost all of them static or with our in-house CMS.

Comment: mb you should write your own form validation on javascript&jquery, it is not too difficult if you have only few required fields.

Comment: pay someone to write that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, it's been a while since I posted this! I figured this out ages ago. Tectite's Formmail script integrates beautifully with reCAPTCHA.

https://www.tectite.com/dlformmail.php